# Add class with "if events"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is pretty much stupid for most of you, but I can't get it to work; I need to add classes based on conditions.

Code:

```
<script>
        if (history.score <= 6,0)
        {
            $('.notabox').addClass('vermelho');
        }
        else if (history.score <= 8,9)
        {
            $('.notabox').addClass('laranja');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.notabox').addClass('verde');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Where does `history` come from? Also, the decimal separator in JavaScript is always `.`. `6,0` should be `6.0`, etc.

Comment: Also, is this script placed after the element it tries modify? If not, you have to wait for the page load.

Comment: `history` comes from another code my brother did, but im guessing this is the problem... anyway, thanks very much guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting @minitech's comment to answer :p

Your code doesn't work because the decimal point is always `.`, not `,` like in some European systems.

That said, judging by your numbers, you could probably do this:

```
    if (history.score <= 6)
        $('.notabox').addClass('vermelho');
    else if (history.score < 9)
        $('.notabox').addClass('laranja');
    else
        $('.notabox').addClass('verde');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated code

```
if (history.score <= 6.0)
{
    $('.notabox').addClass('vermelho');
}
else if (history.score <= 8.9)
{
    $('.notabox').addClass('laranja');
}
else
{
    $('.notabox').addClass('verde');
}
```

Don't use comma(,) for the decimal point ( i.e : 6,0 and 8,9 updated with decimal point 6.0 and 8.9)